# Sort columns based on another column in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, sorting, vlookup

I have a column (say A) that has numeric values, but **not sorted**.

Now, I have a some more columns, (say B, C and D); and column B has all the data in column A but in a different order. The values in columns C and D correspond to the values in B.

My question is, how can I order columns B, C and D in same the order as A? I've tried VLOOKUP but it doesn't seem to help.

P.S. I've looked at [Excel: Order a column based on another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590185/excel-order-a-column-based-on-another-column) which is similar but the VBA code in the accepted answer is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you just try using tables? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-excel-tables-HA010048546.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort B:D (say A>Z). Add a column, say A, with a sequential counter (1, 2, 3 ....) and sort the ColumnsA:B on ColumnB A>Z. Sort A:E on ColumnA ascending.